# Terminology for a probability being likely to affect a non-zero number of trials?

Tags: probability, terminology

This question is probably a duplicate, but since it's about terminology, I don't know how to search for it.

Is there a term for a probability having the quality of being likely to affect a non-zero number of trials? For example, if something is predicted to affect 5% of 1000 trials, then it's likely that approximately 50 trials will be affected, and this can be confirmed. But if something is predicted to affect 5% of 10 trials, then there's only a small chance that even one trial will be affected, and the effect will be difficult or impossible to measure.

My purpose is to read up on the subject and understand if and when it's appropriate for research to make claims like the latter (5% of 10 trials). This was prompted by studies that make claims about things like the effects of policing policy on crime, in cities where there are so few crimes that the claimed effect would likely be plus or minus less than one homicide a year, etc.

Comment: Would terms like "rare" or "unusual" fit your concept?

Comment: @whuber Perhaps my edit answers your question.

Comment: It's hard to say.  Now it sounds like you are looking for terms related to "insufficient data" or "highly uncertain."

Comment: @whuber That would be my predisposition when I see things like this called a "strong result." I'm testing my bias that social science is fake.

Comment: Ah, that's a different direction again!  Look for ["failure to replicate,"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Replication_crisis) "p hacking," and related terms.

Comment: I am not sure I understand your question. But let's assume there is a 5% chance of becoming a criminal for a child born in a family where one parent suffers from drug addiction. If we observe 10 children born in such a situation, there is a ~60% chance that none of them will be a criminal, but ~40% chance that at least one of them will be. That is not what I call "a small chance that even one trial will be affected". This is computed using the binomial distribution: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution